# Java, converting string to integers then add all the integers together

Tags: java

I need to add 8 numbers together from a string.E.g. If someone enters say 1234 it will add the numbers together  1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10 then 1 + 1 = 2. I have done this so far. I cannot figure out how to add these numbers up using a for loop.

```
String num2;     
String num3;   
num2 = (jTextField1.getText());
num3 = num2.replaceAll("[/:.,-0]", "");

String[] result = num3.split("");

int inte = Integer.parseInt(num3);

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

// Stuck

}
```

Comment: Actually `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` = `10`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about that (I skipped exceptions...):

```
String[] sNums = jTextField1.getText().replaceAll("[^1-9]", "").split("(?<!^)");
int sum = 0;
for (String s : sNums) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(s); // add all digits
}

while (sum > 9) { // add all digits of the number, until left with one-digit number
    int temp = 0;
    while (sum > 0) {
        temp += sum % 10;
        sum = sum / 10;
    }
    sum = temp;
}
```

Comment: It's a complete solution. +1.

Comment: Very cool solution! I've always had a thing for digital roots, neat to see it done in code.

Comment: Nice idea, but i get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString` because `sNums[0]` contains a empty String after the split. (Adding `sNums[0] = "0";` solves that)

Answer (score 0):

For every element in result, you need to convert it to an int, then add it to some variable, maybe called sum.

```
int sum = 0;

// for every String in the result array
for (int i = 0; i < BOUND; i++) { 
  // convert s[i] to int value
  // add the int value to sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This pseudo code should do it without splitting, arrays etc.

```
String s = "1234.56";
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < s.length()) {
    char c = s.charAt(i)
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') sum += c - '0';
    i++;
}
```

Should result in sum = 21

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int addAll(String str) {
    str = str.replaceAll("[^1-9]", "");
    if (str.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    char[] c = str.toCharArray();
    Integer result = c[0] - 48;
    while (c.length > 1) {
        result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            result += c[i] - 48;
        }
        c = result.toString().toCharArray();
    }
    return result;
}
```